# Ubuntu 18.04 : how to use Lightning (Thunderbird calendar) in place of Gnome agenda?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, calendar, lightning

Coming from Ubuntu 16.04, I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and appreciate a lot of Gnome features. It is very well polished...

I have a few calendars defined in Lightning (a Thunderbird extension) which sync' with a Baikal server (and then with my smartphone).

Is it possible to have Gnome using those calendars in place of the default Gnome agenda ? 
I have tried using "add calendar from web", but Baikal URL does not work. It seems from what I read that I would need to install evolution because the sync' part of Gnome agenda is managed by evolution...

As Thunderbird is the default email app with Ubuntu, I am reluctant to install evolution on my desktop.

Is there any way to achieve this dream ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found an solution : there is an Thunderbird extension that does what I want.
[EDS Calendar integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/thunderbird/addon/eds-calendar-integration/) integrates calendars events with Gnome clock applet.
And there is nothing else to install, as evolution-data-server is already part of Ubuntu 18.04.
You only need to install v0.5 (last one is v0.5.1) to be compliant with Thunderbird v52.
Cool ! 8-)